# Renderizar css ao transformar view em string

Tags: c#, .net, view

Estou utilizando o método:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

Para transformar minha view em string, para enviar por e-mail, porém, no e-mail a view fica sem css, mesmo adicionando os css no `<head>`

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Como faço para que no e-mail apareça o css ?

Answer (score 1):

Os arquivos de CSS não são carregados em e-mails, a maneira de estilizar um e-mail enviado com HTML é com estilo inline ou, carregar uma tag style (na mesma string do e-mail) com todas as classes e aí sim, utilizar as classes.

Answer (score 0):

Como Gustavo Santos disse os arquivos CSS não são carregados em um e-mail, pode ser usada a tag `<style>` para Hotmail, Yahoo!, e Windows Live Mail, mas vale ressaltar que no GMail ele tira a tag e seu conteúdo.

Eu costumo usar uma ferramenta para botar o CSS inline, o [PreMailer](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net):

```
string html = /*busca o seu html*/;

using(var preMailer = new PreMailer(html))
{
     //Aqui podem ser passados parâmetros, como BaseUri, para montar os <link>'s corretamente
     html = pm.MoveCssInline();
}
```